# NextJS, getStaticProps returns data but data in props but data not available in main function and on client browser

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My getStaticProps function populates the caseStudies object with multiple elements and returns in the props.  When I attempt to read the props to display them the caseStudies Object is empty.  I cannot figure out what is the issue, any ideas?

Below is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Footer from '../shared/components/footer/footer.component';
import Header from '../shared/components/header/header.component';
import { ContentfulService } from '../core/contentfulService';

export default function IndexPage({ id, caseStudies, preview }) {

    console.dir(caseStudies);
    //In browser this displays an empty Array

    const mid = Math.ceil(caseStudies.length / 2);
    const leftColCaseStudies = caseStudies.splice(0, mid);
    const rightColCaseStudies = caseStudies.splice(-mid);

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div>BODY</div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};

export async function getStaticProps({ preview = false }) {

    const service = new ContentfulService();
    const page = await service.fetchHomePageBySlug('homepage');
    const id = page.id;
    const caseStudies = page.cs;

    console.dir(caseStudies);
    //displays multiple caseStudies objects

    return {
        props: { id, caseStudies, preview }
    }
}
```

In addition, the browser is showing the following:

```
Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>.
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at IndexPage (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:42:20)
    at div
    at LocomotiveScrollProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-locomotive-scroll/module/LocomotiveScroll.context.js:13:37)
    at LCApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.tsx:55:27)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/client.js:8:20746)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/client.js:8:23395)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:323:9)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:820:26)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:944:27)
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your `_app` file?